# No matching provisioning profiles found when exporting the app from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I'm trying to export my app out of xcode so I can upload it to the app store but I'm facing, after clicking product -> archive and then trying to export or validate the app I just see these errors, I've tried creating a new project and downloading new provision profiles but it didn't work.. Thanks for help

Screenshots:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OWsI.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7sq5.png

Comment: have u added you team profile@user3347446

Comment: you need to update(set) the correct provisioning profile in the Build settings, once you modified or added a profile at portal.